# How can a variable I pass into a function be undefined in that function?

Tags: javascript

The function "subset" tells me that "largest" is undefined.

What is going on?

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr)
{
    arr.sort();
    var largest = arr.pop()
    console.log(largest);
    subset([], arr, largest);
}


function subset(soFar, rest, largest)
{
    var sum = 0;
    if (rest.length === 0)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<soFar.length; i++)
        {
            sum+= soFar[i];            
        }
        console.log("sum = "+ sum + " " + largest);
        if (sum === largest) return true;
    }

    else
    {
        var soFar2 = soFar.slice(0);
        soFar2.push(rest[0]);
        subset(soFar,rest.slice(1));
        subset(soFar2, rest.slice(1));
    }
}


ArrayAdditionI([85,3,88,2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass in the third parameter, `largest`, in the recursive function call.

Comment: Or rather, the value `undefined`.

Comment: What does line 4 do then?

Comment: @dwilbank see next answer.

Comment: The code is 100% there. I'm thinking now that I pass it the right variable in line 4, then that variable is wiped out and "undefined" by the recursive calls to the function.

Comment: Got it. I figured the recursive calls would leave "largest" alone instead of wiping it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
subset(soFar,rest.slice(1));
```

Here, you've only passed 2 arguments, but the function expects 3.  In Javascript, instead of this being an error, the rest of the arguments are given the value `undefined`.  You probably want those lines to be:

```
subset(soFar,rest.slice(1), largest);
subset(soFar2, rest.slice(1), largest);
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive calls to subset at the end don't pass the third parameter, so it is given the default value of `undefined`